# OpenAPI v3 HTTPS mocking

Tags: ssl, https, mocking, openapi

I have an OpenAPIv3 schema file for a web service I want to be able to talk to from my app. Before deploying and getting live certs sorted, I want to be able to test that the HTTPS connection is working in my local environment. I have been using Prism for HTTP mocking but AFAIK there is no support for HTTPS at all. Does anyone know of any alternative tools which support this functionality? I had a look at MockServer but the docs on setting up an HTTPS connection is flakey and there doesn't seem to be any quality literature to review from a cursory google search. Any ideas / suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Configuring HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) is a breeze with the [API Simulator](https://apisimulator.io/docs/latest/standalone-api-simulator/running-api-simulator.html#https-configuration) using one of: cert and key in PEM format, JKS, or self-issued cert generated on-the-fly. At this time, though, the API Simulator doesn't support importing OpenAPIv3 schema file to create remote stubs/mocks. (Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the API Simulator).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, being able to generate stubs from a schema is a nice to have but not essential, its more important that I can test the HTTPS connection, as my HTTP mock does all the validation I need. Ill certainly have a look at this as adding some dummy responses looks very easy and nice to use!

Answer (score 1):

[**Specmatic**](https://specmatic.in/) allows you to leverage an OpenAPI 3 specification as a mock with https.

Here are the steps

- [Download specmatic](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#setup)
- Create a [sample API Specification](https://specmatic.in/documentation/service_virtualization_tutorial.html#pre-requisites) or leverage your own specification
- [Run the OpenAPI Specification as a mock server with https](https://specmatic.in/documentation/service_virtualization_tutorial.html#ssl--https--stubbing)

Just to clarify, [Specmatic Smart Mocking](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-stub) is just part of its capability. Specmatic is a [Contract Driven Development](https://specmatic.in/#executable-contracts) tool, that allows you to leverage your OpenAPI Specification as a "[Contract as Test](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-test)", [backward compatibility](https://specmatic.in/#backward-compatibility) verification and more. Here is a short [explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HPgpvd8MGg&list=PL9Z-JgiTsOYRERcsy9o3y6nsi5yK3IB_w).

Disclosure: I am lead developer and CTO at Specmatic

Answer (score 0):

Mockintosh does support HTTPS out of the box. By default, it would use self-signed certificates. You can provide your own certificate files via configuration options.

You can take your OpenAPIv3 schema and run it as-is, the mock will serve from whatever you have in your schema.

SSL options described: https://mockintosh.io/Configuring.html#ssl-support
Serving mocks directly from OpenAPI/Swagger: https://mockintosh.io/#automatic-conversion